# How can the specific Group Policy setting which triggers an error in an application be discovered?

Tags: group-policy

When running a new application in an environment with myriad Group Policy restrictions set, the Group Policy (generic) error message appears: "This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer.  Please contact your system administrator".

In order to try and enable the program to work properly with the GP setup, it is essential to know which specific GP restriction was infringed.  How can this information be obtained?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that people often ignore is the Event Viewer. You should check in there and make sure it's enabled. If it is, then maybe your answer is in there. If not, then you might be able to find a 3rd party debugging app that will run in the background and record all the I/O for any particular process. Otherwise, start changing the GPO, one item at a time until you discover the one that's causing you fits.

Comment: That's the first place I looked. Plenty of information on the actual operation of Group Policy itself, but not on any triggering of it at the application level. I might have missed it, but I have made some effort to go through it in detail.